# A website I am trying to scrape yields much faster response for a python script compared to a node.js script

Tags: javascript, python, http, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape this [site](https://ktu.edu.in/eu/core/announcements.htm) with node.js but the response is too slow to complete, taking over a minute on average.

Requesting the same site with python fetches the results in under a couple seconds

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const url = "https://ktu.edu.in/eu/core/announcements.htm";

console.log("Fetching the website");
const res = await fetch(url);

console.log("Request completed");

const data = await res.text();
console.log("Website fetched: Node");

console.log(data);
```

Here is the [repl](https://replit.com/join/gnhbfmeeqg-akhill1) to test the code. I think the server is sending the response in too many "chunks"(you can see it if you run the repl)? Can this be solved from my side? Also why doesn't python have any issues with this?

I have tried setting the same request headers for node.js and python(requests library).

I used the https, axios and node-fetch modules with node.js, same result.

Comment: Does the slowness go away if you remove `console.log(data);`?

Comment: Okay so that fixed it in the repl! But removing the log on my computer doesn't change anything

Comment: @James I updated the node.js version from v16 to 18.17 and that has fixed the problem!

Comment: close the question then please